# How to retain certain fields of the data frame that I don't want to group over?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe with the following fields:

DF:

```
Key 1, Key 2, Key 3, Key 4, Value 1, Value 2
```

Step 1: What I want to do is group over Keys 1, 2, 3, and 4 originally and find the mean of Value 1 as well as Value 2.

Step 2: My goal is to find the maximum of Value 1 when grouping over keys 1, 2, and 3, so I then group over Keys 1, 2, 3 and call the max. However, I want the value of Value 2 that corresponds to the actual max Value 1 results, meaning I want to keep the original Value 2 that is associated with the max value .

```
df.groupby(['Key 1', 'Key 2', 'Key 3'], as_index=False).max()
```

^ When the following is called, it simply finds the max Value 2 as well, while what I really want is simply the max Value 1, and its corresponding Value 2.

As an example:
For df with fields

```
Key1, Key2, Key3, Key4, Value1, Value2:

k1, k2, k3, k4, 30, 10

k1, k2, k3, k4, 20, 20
```

When using groupby from above, this returns `k1, k2, k3, 30, 20`, while what I want is `k1, k2, k3, 30, 10`

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go about it using [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation):

```
df['Value1max'] = df.groupby(['Key 1', 'Key 2', 'Key 3'])['Value1'].transform('max')
```

So if this is you dataframe:

```
  Key1 Key2 Key3 Key4  Value1  Value2
0   k1   k2   k3   k4      30      10
1   k1   k2   k3   k4      20      20
```

You'd get this output:

```
  Key1 Key2 Key3 Key4  Value1  Value2  Value1max
0   k1   k2   k3   k4      30      10         30
1   k1   k2   k3   k4      20      20         30
```